# How can i create load more button with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have got this ajax

```
$(".V_C").click(function() {            
        var shown=4;
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '../connect.php',
                data:"Shown="+shown ,
                success:function(data) {
                    shown=shown+4;
                }         
            });     
    });
```

connect.php

```
if (isset($_GET['Shown'])) {
    $_SESSION['Shown']=$_GET['Shown'];
}
```

and feed.php

```
          if (isset($_SESSION['Shown'])) {
            $ShowC=$_SESSION['Shown'];
          }else{
            $ShowC=4;
          }            
          $Commentsq=$con->query("SELECT * FROM comments  ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT $ShowC");
```

But my code is not working it is stuck at 4

Comment: The variable "shown" in your javascript is set to 4, i don't see anywhere where it is being set to another value. Where is this value supposed to come from?

Comment: @gmfm success:function(data) {
                    shown=shown+4;
                }

Comment: that's in the success function, after the ajax is returned. Is there a point when that variable is changing in your web app. That is where the value of the variable should be coming from. As this code stands there is no way for "shown" to equal anything other than 4 unless somehow that is already set to something different in the session.

Comment: its stuck at 4 since you're not giving any offset on the rows selected

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do requires that you have the **AN OFFSET FOR THE LIMIT** *but you just have none.* The SQL should read something like this:

```
      //IMPLIES: SELECT ONLY $ShowC RECORDS FROM comments... STARTING FROM $startIndex
      $Commentsq = $con->query("SELECT * FROM comments  ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT $ShowC OFFSET $startIndex"); //WHERE START INDEX IS WHERE TO START SELECTING
```

At the onset; your $startIndex could be 0. However, you want to set up a way of knowing the where to $startFrom the next time. Using a $_GET Variable is common Practice but since you are using $_SESSION, You might have to figure out a way to store this in the $_SESSION Variable....

Comment: Cool, I'll post a `Shown` parameter of `1; DROP DATABASE DbName;#`

Answer (score 0):

Each time the element with the class ".V_C" is clicked it resets the value of var shown to '4' right before the ajax is fired. and eventhough your adding to the shown variable in the success function your code will immediately reset it to 4 the next time the element is clicked.